# Android - DrawText on Canvas or TextView.draw

Tags: android, canvas, textview

In my Android (`API 10`) game I've used a `MVC pattern`, a `SurfaceView` with a canvas and a `ListView` for input's choice.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<com.gorgo.pirates.MainGamePanel
    android:id="@+id/surface"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center" >
</com.gorgo.pirates.MainGamePanel>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/mylist"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
    android:divider="#00000000"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" >
</ListView>
```

So now I need to show on screen a lot of String (speeches between characters or narrator text): they stay on screen 4 seconds and they hide themself later, I change the text and reuse them and so on.

I've wrote [this Class](http://pastebin.com/bYmzpxCg) that worked but it initialized a new `TextView` every `draw()` call O_O

But I've discovered that I can't create 3 or 4 `TextView` and `setText` whenever I want because of my external Thread that can't modify a `View`. I've tried with an handler with no success.

So I'm thinking about `canvas.drawText()` but I don't know if it's the right way.
I need also that my String automatically fits in my widht (Pastebin's class does it) and uses a custom Font.

Hints? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hints? sure, you have to use this one: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Layout.html

Comment: Ok I'm trying StaticLayout. It seems to work but Size still too small and I can't figure out how to specify a x,y coordinates.

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/s6ti3zp7heb2jxu/2013-04-23%2016.53.06.png) an example, but I want [THIS](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mnvf3a3gvqs9z2t/2013-04-06%2016.55.27.png).

[HERE](http://pastebin.com/3BNVMqcR) you can find the Class
Are width, spacingMult, spacingAdd ok? I can't find any documentation about them :(

Comment: use textPaint.setTextSize(), I'd use spacingAdd == 0 as it's additional spacing imho

Comment: Ok but I prefer to use a dynamic Size that depends on using Device. Is it possible? 
What about gravity of my Layout? I can't find some .setGravity or .setGravity_layout, or the method to set my x,y String position

Comment: I don't understand your question about the size, for x/y use Canvas.translate()

Comment: Sorry pskink, but I believed to fix that, but now I'm figuring out that I Can't change text drawn by *Layout.draw(). I can change it only re-initialising it..is it right way??

Comment: afaik TextView does it every time you call setText (i mey be wrong though) but you can also use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/DynamicLayout.html

Comment: DynamicLayout has not a method to dynamically change his Text :(
Maybe I must create a new Layout instace per String. Only solution?

Comment: but it has text watcher, see https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/text/DynamicLayout.java, field mWatcher

Comment: Maybe I've fixed using Editable passed as text to DynamicLayout.
If I need to change Text I call: edit.replace(0, edit.length(), newString); Too dirty way? xD